Is there a way to delete a message from the outboxstate table in masstransit after receiving an ack?
I am trying to implement an outbox pattern with MassTransit. When rabbitmq is down, my producer project cannot access rabbit, so it adds the relevant message to the outboxstate and outboxmessage tables. When rabbitmq is up and running again, the message in the outboxstate table is forwarded to the queue and the relevant message is deleted from the outboxstate table. However, if rabbitmq goes down after the message is forwarded to the queue, I lose my message because it is in the queue and deleted from the outboxstate table. How can I solve this with Masstransit? Is there a way or setting to perform the deletion from the outboxstate table if ack is true for each message in Masstransit?

MassTransit ensures the message is acknowledged by the broker before moving to the next message. I can't even tell if you're using the built-in transactional outbox or not though, so who knows what your problem is anyway.
